# How to host a react app in custom route using Nginx?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm trying to host express API in the root route(`/`) and react app in the app route(`/app`). If I go to `https://<domain>` then I can access the express app but if I go to `https://<domain>/app` then I can't access the react app. It says:

```
403 Forbidden
nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Here is the config file for Nginx:

```
server {

  server_name <domain>;

  location /app/ {
        root /var/www/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location / {
        proxy_pass https://<ip>:<port>;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = <domain>) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;

  server_name <domain>;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: Where is your react app actually located? With your current `root` setting it should be placed into the `/var/www/html/app` directory (directory name should be equal to your URI prefix), react router should be able to route requests with the `/app/` prefix and your `try_files` directive should be `try_files $uri /app/index.html`.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply due to the Eid. I did what you have said but the problem is, react is requesting for resources at ```/static``` but the resources are located at ```/app/static/```. also many URLs are pointing to ```/``` but it should point on ```/app/``` instead. The app is not working properly.

Comment: Well, sometimes it is enough to add the `<base href="/app/">` element to your `index.html` file. More common case is when you also need to adjust your react router. Here are two articles worth to read: [How to deploy a React app to a subdirectory](https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1) (1), [An elegant solution of deploying React app into a subdirectory](https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/) (2).